# Linq groupBy IGrouping to List<> in a simple/clean way

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I´ve made a refactor at this method. before we had a lot of looping´s and dummy code. This is as far I could go, but I think I could much simpler.

I guess I could direct from the from * group & select put into the list in the correct way.

Would this be possible? or I have to have this loop?

```
private IEnumerable<ESMatchDate> groupBydate(IEnumerable<ESMatch> matches)
{
    List<ESMatchDate> lMatchDates = new List<ESMatchDate>();

    if (null != matches && matches.Any())
    {
        var dates = from ESMatch in matches
                group ESMatch by ESMatch.BeginDate.ToShortDateString() into newGroup
                orderby Convert.ToDateTime(newGroup.Key)
                select newGroup;

        foreach (var d in dates)
            lMatchDates.Add( new ESMatchDate 
                { Date = Convert.ToDateTime(d.Key), Matches = d.ToList()} );

    }
    else
        lMatchDates = null;

    return lMatchDates;
}
```

Comment: Probably best to ask in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Btw, i assume `BeginDate` is a `DateTime` variable and you want to truncate the time. Your approach via string and conversion is not good, use: `group ESMatch by ESMatch.BeginDate.Date into newGroup`. Then you don't need to do any conversions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the projection in the `select`:

```
private IEnumerable<ESMatchDate> groupBydate(IEnumerable<ESMatch> matches)
{
    if (matches == null || !matches.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }

    return (from ESMatch in matches
            group ESMatch by ESMatch.BeginDate.Date into newGroup
            orderby Convert.ToDateTime(newGroup.Key)
            select new ESMatchDate 
            {
                Date = newGroup.Key,
                Matches = newGroup.ToList()
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: going back and forth to a date string is a bit obsolete. Just do `ESMatch.BeginDate.Date`

Comment: Minor issue, OP wants to return a list, even if your approach compiles it's not the same.

Comment: @Jamiec - Thanks :) fixed

Answer (score 6):

You're so close, but you dont need to manually `Add` to the list - LINQ can do this all for you

```
private IEnumerable<ESMatchDate> groupBydate(IEnumerable<ESMatch> matches)
{

    if (null == matches || !matches.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }
    return matches.GroupBy(x => x.BeginDate.Date)
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                  .Select(x => new ESMatchDate{ Date = x.Key, Matches = x.ToList() }) 
                  .ToList();
}
```

Note this is the same as previous answer just using Lamda syntax instead for comparison. I personally prefer this syntax, but its a matter of taste.